# How to Print Array Of object in EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to print a userlist in a table using ejs into HTML template in Node js. So I am creating a API, my function is

```
const UsersReport = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find().select(
      "name email mobile userType activeStatus photo accountType"
    );

    console.log("users", users);
    let pdf_path = path.normalize("public/user");
    if (!fs.existsSync(pdf_path)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(pdf_path);
    }
    const template = fs.readFileSync(
      path.resolve("templates/userList/index.html"),
      "utf8"
    );

    const content = ejs.render(template, users);
    let fullPdfPath = pdf_path + "/users.pdf";
    fs.writeFile(pdf_path + "/users.html", content, () => {
      let port = 5000;
      const url = `http://localhost:${port}/user/users.html`;
      const option = {
        format: "A4",
        path: fullPdfPath,
        printBackground: true,
      };
      const file = {
        url,
      };
      console.log("generating pdf");
      html_to_pdf.generatePdf(file, option).then((pdfbuf) => {
        console.log("pdf sent successfully");
        return response(res, StatusCodes.OK, true, "user/users.pdf", null);
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return response(
      res,
      StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
      false,
      error,
      error.message
    );
  }
};
```

Here users return an array of object.

My HTML Template code is

```
<tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <% for(let i = 0; i <= users.length; i++ ){ %>
          <td><%= users[i].name %></td>
          <td><%= users[i].mobile %></td>
          <% } %>
      </tr>
```

But I didn't get the result this showing the following error

> {
> "status": false,
> "data": {
> "path": ""
> },
> "message": "ejs:21\n    19|           \r\n    20|           \r\n >> 21|             <% for(let i = 0; i <= users.length; i++
> ){ %>\r\n    22|             <%= users[i].name %>\r\n    23|
>
> \r\n    24|             \r\n\nusers is not defined" }

How can I solve this one?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, users should be in brackets (see [examples](https://ejs.co/) on main page):

```js
const content = ejs.render(template, { users });
```

to use something in a template, it should be given as a property in an object. `{ users }` is just shorthand for `{ users: users }`.